# How to get bytes from a BinaryField in Django?

Tags: python, django, memory, hash, binary

Consider we have a model with a `BinaryField`:

```
from django.db import models
import hashlib

class Target(models.Model):
    # ...
    image = models.BinaryField(max_length=(1<<24)-1)
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return hashlib.md5().update(self.image).hexdigest()
```

Does the above code compute correctly the MD5  digest of the image?
Or is there some method or variable inside `BinaryField` to get the memory to pass to the `update()` method?

UPDATE: When I try:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> t = Target(image=Path('../../Experiments/LoginError2.jpg').read_bytes())
>>> t
```

I'm getting the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'`

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what happened when you tried this? (You'd have to use `self.image`, at the very least, to access the value)

Comment: A `BinaryField` is no different from `IntField` or `StringField`, access it to get the value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm just starting programming in Python, so I find it difficult to try given that I don't have implemented a way for uploading images yet.

Comment: @SergeRogatch You can write a small [test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/) to find out. Or you can even use [`manage.py shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) to create a model to test the behaviour.

Comment: I've updated my question with the results of what happens when I try to load an image.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to your update about the `AttributeError`, you're calling the `hexdigest()` method incorrectly.

The thing is, `update()` method returns `None`, and you're pretty much trying to call `hexdigest()` on `None`. Chaining method calls like this only works if the previous method returns an actual object instead of `None`.

You'll have to do this call in multiple steps:

```
def __str__(self):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(self.image)
    return m.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's the conclusion: `BinaryField` can be assigned bytes and can be read as bytes.

In the above code the hashing was done wrongly, and the correct way is:

`hashlib.md5(self.image).hexdigest()`